# Serilog request logging ends up in event log

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, serilog, event-log

This is an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application. I have Serilog request logging as described in https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/ and https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore, and it works fine. The only problem is that it's also writing every HTTP request to the Windows Event Log, which is just making that worthless because now anytime I want to find exception information, the haystack has become huge.

My setup look like this. As you can see, I don't have the EventLog sink registered.

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE)
#if DEBUG
                .WriteTo.Debug(outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE)
#else
                .WriteTo.File(new Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(), LOG_FILE_PATH)
#endif
            ;
            Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateBootstrapLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting up");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration // 2-stage initialization so that we use the config values: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                    .ReadFrom.Services(services)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE)
#if DEBUG
                    .WriteTo.Debug(outputTemplate: LOG_TEMPLATE)
#else
                    .WriteTo.File(new Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(), LOG_FILE_PATH)
#endif
                , writeToProviders: true)
```

It turns out that if I have `writeToProviders: true` set, then nothing gets written to the Event Log, but I actually need that because I have a custom `ILogger` and `ILoggerFactory` (we use [JSNLog](https://jsnlog.com/) to log Javascript errors and write them to ELMAH), so I'm guessing there must be a default Microsoft sink that puts things in the Event Log or something.

Is there a way to work around this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a long time to finally figure this out, but the key was to go back through the [Microsoft logging documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/) and see that the logging component comes with four providers by default: console, debug, EventSource, and EventLog (when running on Windows), so when I used `writeToProviders: true`, that caused my request logging to get pushed into the Event Log. The solution was to be sure and clear all the default providers, then re-add the Event Log one and set the minimum level to Warning.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddEventLog(options =>
            options.Filter((s, level) => level >= LogLevel.Warning));
    }
    .UseSerilog(...)
```

Comment: I had the same problem. You made my day, with this. Thanks!